# Click event for a class but not when another class is included

Tags: jquery

I have a `div` that has a class of `TaskItem`.  When you click the class an event is fired.

However, when that same div contains a second class called `TaskSelected`, i don't want the click even to fire.

Is it possible to do this in a single selector or do I need to check for the existence of the class within the click event?

Comment: Post an [mcve] in your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.TaskItem:not(.TaskSelected)').click(function() {
  alert('click')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='TaskItem'>no class TaskSelected</div>
<div class='TaskSelected TaskItem'>hass class TaskSelected</div>
```

Do this use [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/) selector

> Description: Remove elements from the set of matched elements.

```js
$('.TaskItem').click(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).hasClass('TaskSelected')) {
    return false
  }

  alert('click')

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='TaskItem'>no class TaskSelected</div>
<div class='TaskSelected TaskItem'>hass class TaskSelected</div>
```

Another option is use [.hasClass](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)

> Description: Determine whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.

Comment: @guradio how did you embed that run code snippet block??

Comment: Why `e.target` instead of `this`?

Comment: @Tara https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: could be but why not use e.target?it would still target the same element right? @4castle

Comment: @griegs glad to help i could more possible solution but it would be too long :) hope the given are enough to solve your problem. happy coding mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  $("body").on('click','.TaskItem:not(.TaskSelected)',function() {console.log("clicked");});
```